# Dynamic linq query in EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using dynamic LINQ query in EF4.

Below code throws error: **'New' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function.**

```
var x = ent.OM_COMPANY
    .Where(qry)
    .OrderBy("it.CM_CODE")
    .Select("New(it.CM_CODE, it.CM_NAME)");
```

What am I doing wrong?

The below code executes without any error.

```
var x = from cmp in ent.OM_COMPANY 
        where (qry) 
        orderby cmp.CM_CODE  
        select new { cmp.CM_CODE, cmp.CM_NAME };
```

Comment: what with `new { c1 = cmp.CM_CODE, c2 = cmp.CM_NAME }`

Comment: @tschmit007 sorry i posted the question wrong.I've update it now.Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know how you got that first code block to compile. Both `OrderBy` and `Select` take lambdas not strings. It should be written as:

```
var x = ent.OM_COMPANY
    .Where(qry)
    .OrderBy(c => c.CM_CODE)
    .Select(c => c.CM_CODE, c.CM_NAME);
```